# How to write regular expression to check if substring starts with range of characters?

Tags: regex

Thanks for your help in advance.

I want to check if a substring would start within range of characters after a prefix

For example, I have the following strings with prefix 'abc_xyz$'

```
abc_xyz$Item Ledger_Entry_CT
abc_xyz$Purchase
```

To check if string after prefix would start G thru R, I have written the following regular expression,

```
abc_xyz\$^[G-Rg-r].*
```

Unfortunately it does not help.

Here are use cases

```
abc_xyz$Item Ledger_Entry_CT --> should match since first char in 'Item' matches thru G and R
abc_xyz$Purchase --> should match since first char in 'Purchase' matches thru G and R
abc_xyz$Customer --> should NOT match since first char in 'Customer' do not match thru G and R
abc_xyz$Sales --> should NOT match since first char in 'Sales' do not match thru G and R
```

Any help?

Comment: how is this java related? Check this website https://regex101.com/

Comment: `^` is out of place in your regex. Just remove `^` and it will be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
^abc_xyz\$[G-Rg-r].*
^abc_xyz\$(?i:[g-r]).*
^abc_xyz\$(?i)[g-r].*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T8KReM/1).

The pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `abc_xyz\$` - a `abc_xyz$` fixed string
- `[G-Rg-r]` - `G` to `R` or `g` to `r` letters
- `.*` - the rest of the line.

Note the `(?i:[g-r])` inline modifier group makes the `[g-r]` pattern part case insensitive.

The `(?i)` part makes all the pattern parts to the right of it case insensitive.